# Remove double quotes inside another double quotes using java

Tags: java, regex, string, replace, double-quotes

I have a string which contains double quotes inside another double quotes.

Eg:

**Input1:**

```
<span style="font-family: pp-sans-big-light, "Noto Sans", Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, "sans serif"; font-size: 17px; text-align: start; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="transaction" name="details"> How are you</span>
```

**Expected output1:**

```
<span style="font-family: pp-sans-big-light, Noto Sans, Calibri, Trebuchet, Arial, sans serif; font-size: 17px; text-align: start; background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);" class="transaction" name="details"> How are you</span>
```

**Input 2:**

```
<span title="Conditional (A/B) Content on "Transactions.Recipient Name"" class="transaction" name="details"> Transaction Recipient</span>
```

**Expected Output 2:**

```
<span title="Conditional (A/B) Content on Transactions.Recipient Name" class="transaction" name="details"> Transaction Recipient</span>
```

I tried the below options,

**Option 1:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        int i;
        String title = null, style = null, temp = null;
        String tempNodeValue = "<?xml version=\"1.0\"?><dummyroot>+/**INPUT_HERE**/+</dummyroot>";
//        tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replace("\"","&quot;");
        DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
        Document document = db.parse(new InputSource(new StringReader(tempNodeValue)));
        NodeList nodeList = document.getElementsByTagName("span");
        for(i=0;i<nodeList.getLength(); i++){
            Node node =nodeList.item(i);
            if(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title") != null){
                title = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("title").getNodeValue();
                temp = title.replace("\"","'");
                tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replace("&quot;","\"");
                tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replace(title,temp);

            }
            if(node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("style") != null){
                style = node.getAttributes().getNamedItem("style").getNodeValue();
                temp = style.replace("\"","'");
                tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replace("&quot;","\"");
                tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replace(style,temp);
            }
        }
        System.out.println(tempNodeValue);

    }
```

**Option 2:**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{
        String tempNodeValue = /**INPUT_HERE**/;
        tempNodeValue = tempNodeValue.replaceAll("\"(\\b[^\"]+|\\s+)?\"(\\b[^\"]+\\b)?\"([^\"]+\\b|\\s+)?\"","\"$1$2$3\"");
        System.out.println(tempNodeValue);
    }
```

I gave a try with jsoup as well. But none of them worked. Option 2 worked for input 2 but it is not working for input 1. Option 1 is also not working. Can someone please help me on this? I went through all the existing answers in stackoverflow, none of them helped.

Comment: I have a feeling that there are cases not described here. How do you know which quotes are "inside" other ones and are not just top-level quotes? I think the requirements are unclear.

Comment: Hi @arcadeblast77, the string we are considering here is a html attribute. I think you can come at it from that point. so for that attribute value I need to keep the outer double quotes and remove all the inner double quotes

Comment: Deleted my response because it didn't capture some edge cases. I am suspicious that this problem is solvable in a part of the stack we're not seeing, or by a library. I know you mentioned trying jsoup but I'm still leaning toward a library for this. (If I knew which one, I'd post.) Also, is there any chance this is an XY Problem? https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: Why do you have this string? Where did the invalid HTML come from?

Comment: @user207421 We have a aloha editor in our webapp, which introduces this invalid html.

Answer (score 0):

**UPDATED

My old answer didn't work, but this is a fun question and I think I've got a solution for it.

So first identify the starts and ends of quotes that you want. This regex does that:

```
 ">|\"? [a-z]+="
```

If you split on this regex, any quotes in the resulting strings are unnecessary.

```
 let originalString = "<span title="Conditional (A/B) Content on "Transactions.Recipient Name"" class="transaction" name="details"> Transaction Recipient</span>";
 originalString.split(/">|\"? [a-z]+="/)
```

Yields

```
 let attributeContents = [
      "<span",
      "Conditional (A/B) Content on \"Transactions.Recipient Name\"",
      "transaction",
      "details",
      " Transaction Recipient</span>"
 ];
```

Now, all you have to do is loop through these sub strings, and if they have any quotes, replace the string with quotes with the string without quotes in the original.

```
 for(let index in attributeContents) {
      let attributeValue = attributeContents[index];
      originalString = originalString.replace(attributeValue, attributeValue.replace(/"/g, "");
 }
 // double comments have now been removed from the original string.
```

Comment: Thanks for your time Chris!! Good suggestion!. There may be multiple attributes in the string so the prefix part will work. Identifying the suffix will not work. Could you consider this use case <span title="Conditional (A/B) Content on "Transactions.Recipient Name"" class="transaction" name="details"> Transaction Recipient</span>?

Comment: @KishoreMohanavelu I updated my answer,  does this solution work for you?

Comment: Thanks again Chris! Will test your solution today and update you.